How not to save data from Inline Django Model?
I'm trying to implement the ability to view users' locations in a task through the inline Geoposition model.
Geoposition stores latitude and longitude, then thanks to changing the tabular.html template I display the map
When I try to save the model, I get an error: The number of GET/POST parameters exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS, because data from this Geoposition inline trying to POST. I would not like to change this setting.
In this case, the inline model class looks like this
class TaskTransitInline(admin.TabularInline):
    template = "admin/gis/tabular_override.html"
    model = Geoposition
    extra = 0
    max_num = 0
    can_delete = False
    fields = (
        "id",
        "task",
        "created_at",
        "longitude",
        "latitude",
        "speed",
    )
    readonly_fields = ["id", "task", "created_at", "longitude", "latitude", "speed"]

Why do I then see ID and task in the data POST?
Maybe someone can help me
